# Visual Studio Code Pre-formatting HTML document

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, format

I would like to Pre-format when I create a new HTML document so I can get some already link and meta tag on it . By default I have this pre format below but i would like to add more and take out some of the tag. Would you recommand me how to make it ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: define a snippet

Comment: how can i define it ?

Comment: look in the VSC doc for Snippets

Answer (score 0):

To improve the formatting of your HTML source code, you can use the Format Document command **`Ctrl+Shift+I`** to format the entire file or Format Selection **`Ctrl+K Ctrl+F`** to just format the selected text.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html